# switch to x server window using alt tab program switcher

Tags: windows, alt-tab, x-server, cygwin-x

For x server (Cygwin X server hosted on windows platform) the alt-tab program switcher does not work. The x server window (in my case gvim) does not show up in the list of windows when using alt-tab. Although the window is present in the taskbar at the bottom of the screen. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you start XWin with the `-keyhook` option, alt-tab will work. See the [XWin(1)](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/XWin.1.html) manpage. You can do this by creating the file `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` with the following contents:

```
exec X :0 -keyhook
```